# How to solve the route changing to another when I make a scroll to the section of the same page in Laravel 8?

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I am using blade template for laravel and I want to make a navigation link that scrolls to the section of the same route.

Here is the code example...

```
<li class="nav-item">
   <a class="nav-link" href="#ask_for_help">Ask for Help</a>
</li>
<div id="ask_for_help">
   The section that I want to reach.
</div>
```

It did reach to this section, but the route changes to

```
localhost:8000/#ask_for_help
```

instead of staying at the same route

```
localhost:8000
```

Comment: That is the same route. What you’re seeing is standard behaviour of how anchors work.

Comment: Yep, got it. Thanks.